# equivalent mongo db query in php

Tags: php, mongodb, find

Hi I am running a shell mongo db command successfully as below

```
db.main.find({starttime : {$gt :1477267200, $lt : 1477353600},id: "55567"}).pretty();
```

I want equivalent statement in php and tried below but not getting data

```
$cursor=$collection->find(array('starttime' => array(array('$gt' => '1477267200'),array('$lte' => '1477353600'))),array('site_id'=> '55567'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection->find(array(
                "site_id" => 5,
                "starttime" => array('$gt' => 1477267200, '$lt' => 1477353600)));
```

Comment: are you getting any error or is it just you are not getting the expected output.